# ADF run Blob Create event sequentially

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

An ADF activity is triggered when a blob is created (BlobEventsTrigger). If I add 6 files together then the activity is run 6 times parallely. I only want the activity to run once in this case. Or it should execute sequentially (not parallely). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case of an event trigger, for 6 files there would be 6 triggers created. You cannot limit it to 1.
If that is the case you can switch from Event trigger to Scheduled one.

There is an option to have them be sequential as seen below rather than parallel:

[image]